# How to enter data into row/colum

Tags: excel, vba

New to vba here and looking for some help, I have a workbook comprising of 4 sheets, FL1, FL2, FL3, FL4. Each sheet has a Date Columns from 01/03/21 - 31/03/21 (Col B-Col AF) and Time values in Column A2 - A28
There is a userform (Userform1) with 3 comboboxes and one textbox, (cbRoom, cbTime, cbName, txtDate)
and a command button (cmdSave)

What I would like to happen is that the user picks a room from the drop down cboRoom, (which is obviously the sheet names)  chooses a time from dropdown (cboTime), chooses a name from dropdown (cboName) and enters the date manually in the date text field (txtDate) clicks on save and the Data is transferred to whichever sheet was chosen. eg.. Name 'Tony' is transferred to Room1 Sheet, Column (whichever date column was chosen) Row (Whichever Row the Time chosen is)

So far I have

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
       For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       Me.cbRoom.AddItem sh.Name
   Next sh

   Me.cbName.RowSource = ("Counsellor")
   Me.cbTime.RowSource = ("BKTime")

   End Sub
   Private Sub cbTime_Change()
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       cbTime.Value = Format(cbTime.Value, "HH:MM AMPM")
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub

   Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
       On Error Resume Next
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.cbRoom.Value).Activate

   Dim rTime As Range, rDate As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim MyRoom As String
   MyRoom = UserForm1.cbRoom.Value
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MyRoom)

       With Sheets(MyRoom)
           Set rDate = .Range("A:AF") _
           .Find(txtDate.Value, _
           LookIn:=xlValues, _
           lookat:=xlWhole)
    
           Set rTime = .Rows(1) _
           .Find(cbTime.Value, _
           LookIn:=xlValues, _
           lookat:=xlWhole)


        .Cells(rTime.Row, rDate.Column) = cbName.Value
        End With
   End Sub
```

However, I receive a 'Varaible not defined' on this line - Set **rTime** = .Rows(1)
Would appreciate any help and Pointers.

I have changed the code as you suggested Scott, but still having no luck

Regards

Yab

Comment: you do not declare `rTime` .  You need to `Dim rTime as Range`

Comment: ..did I not do that in the 1st line of the cmdSave code, or do I need to move it to a Module?.... Ignore that last comment..been at it long :-)

Comment: I do not see `rTime` I see `rName` and `rDate` but no `rTime`

Comment: Yes you are correct,(I never made sense because I edited my comment after!) OK.. I have declared rTime and now receive en error on  - Set MyRoom = UserForm1.cbRoom.Value ... Object Required

Comment: a `Value` is not an object.  Declare it as a string not an object and remove the word `Set` at the front of that line.

Comment: thanks for the input Scott, I have corrected that, I now receive object variable or with block variable not set on the last line of code, been playing about but unable to find the answer, Is it the way I have refenced the Cell?

Comment: You write that the time values are in A2:A28 - there's no overlap between that range and `.Rows(1)`  Maybe you meant to search in `.Columns(1)` ?

Comment: Hi Scott... Thnaks for the help, I did as you suggested and still same error.